# How can a company be benefited using utility tokens?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

Are there any profits for a company having ERC 20 tokens, if the token price gets hiked?

Answer (score 1):

anyone can make ERC20 tokens. If u are able to code in solidity, then you can make any amount of ERC20 token with any name. But when it comes to token price hiking, its purely based on the maximum number of the transaction occur with your custom made tokens.If all the etehreum users circulate user token via transactions, a value will get added to ur tokens and it gets listed on crypto exchanges. Hope this helps you.